# Training AI models to identify the sex in some bird species

Tags: ornithology, artificial-neural-network

Through my limited knowledge and experience with parrots (especially African greys and quacker parrots), I came to notice that most often some species, in which the male and the female are highly similar, show some slight variations in the form of the beak or the head between the two sexes.

Consequently, I can't help but wonder whether the use of some CNN model could perhaps trace some underlying difference between the two sexes that may go unnoticed to the human eye.

Side note: on the context of the African grey there are some documented difference between the two sexes like the size of the eye, but even those are hard to interpret for the untrained individual. What matters most in my question is the practicality of this idea and the possibility of generalization on different species.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Specifically what is your question? This isn't a discussion forum, so if you're looking for "huh interesting idea I wonder how that would work" etc., take it to [chat]. You'll have to tell us what species you are looking at specifically, and what differences of beak form have been observed specifically. "I have observed" can't lead to a great objective answers. Please [edit] your question to include required detail. Thanks!